# Convert CSV contents to Go interface to upload them to a Google Sheet

Tags: csv, go, google-sheets-api

I am trying to send the contents of a CSV file to a Google Sheet, via their very ill-documented API for Go.

The `BatchUpdate` takes an `interface`, so this would work:

```
values := [][]interface{}{{"one cell", "another cell"}, {"one cell in new row", "another cell in new row"}}
```

The problem comes when I want to send the contents from a CSV. I have done this:

```
func prepare(filename string) [][]interface{} {

    file, _ := os.Open(filename)

    defer file.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    record, err := reader.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error", err)
    }

    all := [][]interface{}{}

    for _, value := range record {
        all = append(all, []interface{}{value})
    }

    return all
}
```

And I believe this should give me the `interface` ready to be inserted in the sheet. However, when I do this later on:

```
rb := &sheets.BatchUpdateValuesRequest{
        ValueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
    }
    rb.Data = append(rb.Data, &sheets.ValueRange{
        Range:  rangeData,
        Values: values, // This is the interface that I returned earlier on
    })
    _, err = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchUpdate(spreadsheetId, rb).Context(ctx).Do()
```

it gives me a `googleapi: Error 400: Invalid data[0]: Invalid values[0][0]`

So I understand that I am trying to pass the CSV fields in an incorrect format. I know that when I do this in `Python`, I need to pass it as tuples for the data to be accepted. What's the correct way to pass the data here in `Go`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what my problem was, when appending, I was doing this:

```
all = append(all, []interface{}{value})
```

And I should have done this

```
all = append(all, []interface{}{value[0], value[1]})
```

This is, because `value` can be indexed, since every item inside of it corresponds to a cell, so my CSV specifically had two cells. Passing just `value` was the wrong format for this.